# close/minimize/maximize controls of windows absent , ctrl+alt+T not working, dash and launcher absent post resizing system partition

Tags: boot, unity, partitioning, gparted

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

My Terminal & Unity are not working.

When login i see my <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is not working, login screen bland, no dash, no launcher. However i am able to run GUI applications from tty1 using command line and then see them after <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. but on desktop there is no minimize, close, maximize button on windows, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> also doesn't work. Could this be caused by low disk space warning originally given by system after which i decided to increase system partition size?

Things I have Tried: 
Reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` with

```
sudo apt-get aptitude install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

**Checking updates, Upgrades & -f install**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From tty;

Run updates:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Check for Errors:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then unmount the deleted drive:

```
umount /media/amit
```

Then update your grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reinstall unity:

```
 sudo apt-get aptitude install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Next Install Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get aptitude install --reinstall gnome-terminal && sudo apt-get update
```

Now Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

**Other Options**:  Reseting unity with `unity-reset`  Install from Link If you can -> [Install unity-reset](https://launchpad.net/~amith/+archive/ubuntutools/+build/3910667/+files/unity-reset_0.1-8_all.deb)

If not you can install `unity-reset` in tty:

Add PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily && sudo apt-get update
```

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

To reset tweak tool

```
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

Then type:

```
$ unity-reset
```

Last option install new desktop from tty this option installs **Gnome Desktop**

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Last Option: [Reinstall Ubuntu Without Loosing Data](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation)

Comment: when am trying to umount /media/amit i get an error stating /media/amit is not mounted(according to mtab). i ran sudo blkid to see my partitions, i see sdb5 is not mentioned(which i had deleted), however sdb6 is present(created by me from unallocated space originally).  Rest commands went smooth except gnome-terminal was already installed. After reboot i am still confronted with same errors.

Comment: If the drivw is unmouted you should be able to format it later with gparted I would worry abut unity first. Updated terminal & unity codes + extra troubleshooting

Comment: i fixed the  first error i.e /media/amit not found during boot process by editing the /etc/fstab file. i had configured it to mount sdb5 on auto during boot process. hence first error solved but rest desktop problem persists. If this input helps, before i decided to increase my ubuntu partition size, ubuntu was complaining me for acutely low disk space of few kb in system partition. Could this have caused this present problem ?

Comment: O definitely but updates should fix the issue - or -f install ; always can try  'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' Just to check newest everything.

Comment: i again tried the given commands. This time it downloaded few packages like cheese, unity, thunderbird gnome etc.on running apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop.  all other commands gave the same response. However i am still facing the problems with desktop.                                                      Is the command sudo apt-get aptitude install as given above correct.

Comment: Added unity-reset option & new desktop you can sub "Grome" with" KDE" or other desktops supported.

Comment: thanks a ton!!!!! reseting unity using unity-tweak-tool worked for me.

Comment: NP Please remember to select the Check Mark!